# how to notify user for approaching VideoMaximumDuration

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using a `UIImagePickerController` for recording a 30 second video.

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.videoMaximumDuration=30.0f;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I want an alarm type notification for user to notify user that video recording time is about to complete.

For example, if my timer for video recording completes 25s then an alarm is started for notifying user that video recording is about to finish at 30 seconds.

Comment: I improved the indenting and made the content a bit easier to read :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using videoMaximumDuration method you can restrict length of video from both ways. Like if you are recording video an alert will popup saying you cannot record video more than 60 sec and if you are selecting any video file from your library, first it will check the length of your video if length is more than 60 sec. Again alert will popup saying video is larger than 60 sec but there will be two options i.e. use or cancel. If you select use then it will crop the length of video upto 60sec from the beginning.

```
imagePickerController.videoMaximumDuration = 60.0f;
```

Comment: Yes, i understand this fact. But now i want is that user may get notified before hand for the fact that his maximum time duration for video recording is about to complete i.e. 5 seconds before the video actually stops and alert gets shown. this notification can be in the form of alarm that beeps 5 second before actual time completion